# How to run asp .net website from index.html and not .aspx file?

Tags: html, asp.net

I need to write a website that runs from index.html file, but I want to use asp methods and properties (such as: Session, Application) in the main page. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Bad idea to put all html pages through asp executer, why can you not use the extension you are supposed to use?

Comment: because its a project for my student and his teacher told him that the project should run from index.html file

Comment: 1) Either your teacher misspoke and meant index.aspx 2) Your teacher is an idiot (trust me I see plenty that do nothing but collect paychecks and understand none of what they teach) or 3) your teacher may expect you to utilize an embedded page or redirection, because if you do not have the access needed to add index.aspx to the servers default page list, then you do not have the access needed to add .html to the accepted APS extensions.

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot do that, because ASP.NET attributes are only allowed in ASP.NET files. The good way is to use .aspx file.

Comment: Technically incorrect, any file extension can be set up by the server to be parsed by the ASP engine.

Comment: oky, suppose there is html page, and i am using the ASP.NET attribute, as <% for(int i=;i<6;i++) %>. This same code will work in .aspx file, but i don't think that it will work in .html file. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: As I said, any extension can be added to those parsed by the ASP engine, Just as any extension can be added to PHP, CGI, Pearl, SHTML engines.